# On path between two vertices of diffenent colour.

Tags: graph-theory

whether for a k-chromatic connected graph on n vertices,every pair of distinct coloured vertices are joined by atleast one path of odd length when the graph is coloured with exactly k number of colours!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is trivially true when $k=2$, since this implies that the graph is bipartite.

It is not true when $k>2$ as you can easily see when you take a $K_k$ with a $P_3$ attached.
Since you have more than two colors you can construct a coloring where the two endpoints of
the $P_3$ have different colors, but nevertheless the only path between them has even length.

However, in this counterexample we could have colored the two endpoints with the same color.
Because your writeup of the question is not very robust, you may have wanted to ask the following,
slightly more interesting question.

If two vertices $v$ and $w$ have different colors in every possible $k$-coloring,
is there always a path of odd length between them?

In this case the answer is 'yes', which can be seen by looking at the Kempe-subgraph containing
$v$ and $w$ (i.e. the subgraph containing all vertices having the same color as either $v$ or $w$).

If $v$ and $w$ are in different components then you can swap colors on one of those components and obtain a proper $k$-coloring where $v$ and $w$ have the same color. Contradiction.

So $v$ and $w$ are in the same component. Since this component is bipartite and $v$ and $w$ are in different partite sets every path between $v$ and $w$ in this component is odd.

Comment: actually i was considering such a situation that the two vertices must be coloured with different colours on each case when the graph is coloured with k no. of colours i.e. what u said,so forgot to add 'If u and v has different colors in every possible k coloring' sorry,i should have been more precise.

Comment: OK. You were able to solve the problem with the given hint?

Comment: Consider the kempe subgraph.then u and v are in same component,as has different colour in any k colouring.if they are adjacent,we are done.if not,there exists a path joining them.since a vertex, next to a vertex of colour same as u, has colour of v along the path and since there are only two colours and a vertex of colour of v is at a odd distance from u along the u-v path,the path is of odd length.is it ok?

Comment: Your explanation may be correct, but I have trouble understanding your English. To be sure I have added some detail to the answer so you can decide for yourself if your answer was OK. No doubt you will write a much better proof in your own language :)

Comment: sorry again.thanks :)